# Popup a href issue

Tags: html, modal-dialog

I have a Modal. I've added treeview in it to which there are href links. When I am trying to click on it, it is not go href site. It is not working in Modal.

Please help me with this issue.

**My HTML code:**

```
<div aria-describedby="modal1Desc" aria-labelledby="modal1Title" class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal" role="dialog" style="max-height:450px; overflow:auto;"><button aria-label="Close" class="remodal-close" data-remodal-action="close"></button>
<link href="https://silsupur.org/WebPart/TreeViewMenu-css?v=4xO27ePt9p3bZ1f5vbsNkq8yPFdQHFtZ47xJbc2v-TI1" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="BaseAccordionMenu bam-easing" id="534f8c94498949fb97f41bd8f77667e5" style="display:none;" >
    <h3></h3>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <i></i>
            <a href="#">homepage</a>
        <ul>
        <li>
            <i></i>
            <a href="#">otherpage</a>
        <ul>
        <li>
            <i></i>
            <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">try1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <i></i>
            <a href="https://www.yandex.com" target="_blank">try2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jquery; (src undifened?)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
var src = $('#modal').children('iframe').attr('src'); //popup ID'si buraya eklenmeli
$('.remodal-close'),$('.remodal-cancel'),$('.remodal-wrapper').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#modal').children('iframe').attr('src', '');
    $('.popup-bg').fadeOut();
});
```

});

Comment: Please provide your modal code.

Comment: @AagamJain i added

Comment: Plz add HTML as well.

Comment: @AagamJain i add well :) help please